# Time difference calculations

Tags: php, time, strtotime, date-arithmetic

This is all driving me crazy here.

`$now = time ();` gives me the timestamp right now.

Question:

does: `$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));` give me the timestamp of seconds of today? starting from `00:00`?

I've been trying to answer it myself by substracting `$now` with the total seconds elapsed since `$today`, but I'm getting a whole different amount.

**EDIT**

Im getting for today:

`1355961600`

and for now:

`1356002627` (+ 1 second every second since I've posted this)

Since the difference is really small I think that should be it, but when I'm trying to calculate myself I don't get the same amount. Might be the difference between my localhost time and real time here... You guys think this is it?

Comment: What is the "different amount" you are getting?

Comment: Are you trying to work out the number of seconds since the beginning of the day?

Comment: yes exactly thats what im trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(it's 12:15 now here):

```
php > echo time() - strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
44116
php > echo 44116 / 3600;
12.254444444444
```

PHP 5.3.10, on Ubuntu 12.04

`time()` will give the seconds from the Unix Epoch (Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC) until "now". `strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))` will give the seconds from the Unix Epoch until 00:00:00 this morning. Subtract those and you get the seconds elapsed today.

Answer (score 1):

It will give the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC till today (current time).

Edit: Look at the answer of Bart Friederichs, both functions do something else.

Comment: i noticed :P but i think it is the right code to get the seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC till todays date

Comment: Sorry, made a little mistake. Time: "Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)." And the other function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.

Answer (score 1):

Your string `$today` is giving you the timestamp from Y-m-d, and not Y-m-d, H:i:s.

If you want to calculate the number of seconds past from this morning, say 8.00 o'clock.

```
$iNow = time();
$iFrom = strtotime(date('20-12-2012, 08:00:00'));

echo $iFrom - $iNow . ' seconds have past.';
```